# How to concatenate two strings in SQL statement?

Tags: mysql, sql, string, sql-update

## The problem

I have a SQL database named "matches" with a textfield named "events". In this event there is some data and I want to add a string to this data. For example: the existing data is "Goal: Aguero" and I want to add, with a SQL statement, the data: ", Yellow card: Ozil", so that I get the result: "Goal: Aguero, Yellow: Ozil"

## What I've already tried

I've tried many things but I don't get the right solution. I've tried the dot function: *'Goal' . 'Yellow'* but it doesn't work. I've also tried the CONCAT() function, but it doesn't work too.

## Some code that I've tried:

```
$sql = "UPDATE matches
SET events.UpdateBy = CONCAT('Goal: Aguero',' ','Yellow card: Ozil')
ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1";

$sql = "UPDATE matches
SET events = 'Goal: Aguero' . ' Yellow card: Ozil'
ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1";
```

Can anyone help me? Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You simply specify the column name as the first argument and use [`CONCAT_WS`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_concat-ws) which is NULL safe i.e. it'll work even if events column is NULL:

```
UPDATE matches
SET events = CONCAT_WS(', ', events, 'Yellow card: Ozil')
WHERE ...
```

[Demo on DB<>Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=5dc9f887fc3ea1601b74cb8357a00c3f)

PS: I would rather suggest creating a table of events e.g. `matchevents(id, event_id, event_type_id, player_id, time, etc)`. It is better that way.

Comment: And how can I add an image (HTML) instead of the first ', ' in this CONCAT_WS function? I have an image of a Yellow card on my server (images/yellowcard.png).

Comment: Perhaps like this: `CONCAT_WS(', ', events, '<img src="..."> Yellow card: Ozil')`.

Comment: You could `TRIM` empty strings.